# adding multiple Views to multiple layouts

Tags: android

I want to add ovals to each view that I have but it seems like it only adds it to the first layout.  Any ideas

Here is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/first_plane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/second_plane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

These are both inside a LinearLayout

Here is the code that I am trying

```
DrawOval firstOval = new DrawOval(this, 400, 20, 650, 100); 
firstOval.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

ViewGroup firstLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.first_plane);
firstLayout.addView(firstOval);

DrawOval secondOval = new DrawOval(this, 200, 150, 450, 230);
secondOval.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

ViewGroup secondLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.second_plane);
secondLayout.addView(secondOval);
```

THank you

Comment: What is a DrawOval object? Maybe you want an ImageView set with a ShapeDrawable set with an OvalShape?

Comment: it is just a random view that draws an oval on the screen. should that matter?

Comment: Well given that your DrawOval class is a custom View you wrote yourself that isn't part of the standard Android Library your bug is probably in that class. Overall I don't see why the code you supplied wouldn't function. I recommend sticking with built-in Android classes whenever possible.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. Do you know of any good tutorials on what you said? I tried to look into it but I couldnt figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To create a shape and add it to standard Android layout I'd suggest taking a look at these two articles. You should be able to create the entire layout with shapes in XML.

http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2012/08/xml-drawables-part-i.html
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html

If you don't want to mix shapes with typical Android widgets like `Button` and `EditText` you can use the [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) class and draw onto the canvas in code.